# Batch file to add numerical prefix to filenames that are based on month strings

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Banks inter alia often supply pdf statements with names that are based on calendar months (January, February, etc.) and these, ofc, end up in 'alphabetical' order inside your folders!

I save the files into a folder for each year (so 12 files in each) but would like a ***simple*** batch file to add a numerical prefix to each filename (01 for Jan, 02 for Feb, etc.) so that Windows Explorer will then display them in the 'correct' order.

I am running Win 10 and need a simple file because my programming skills are very limited.  Can anybody help, please?

Basically I just want a simple batch file that I can place in a folder that, when it's run, will change the filenames in the folder from this:-

```
2017_April_Statement.pdf  
2017_August_Statement.pdf  
2017_December_Statement.pdf  
2017_February_Statement.pdf  
2017_January_Statement.pdf  
2017_July_Statement.pdf  
2017_June_Statement.pdf  
2017_March_Statement.pdf  
2017_May_Statement.pdf  
2017_November_Statement.pdf  
2017_October_Statement.pdf  
2017_September_Statement.pdf
```

to this:-

```
01 2017_January_Statement.pdf  
02 2017_February_Statement.pdf  
03 2017_March_Statement.pdf  
04 2017_April_Statement.pdf  
05 2017_May_Statement.pdf  
06 2017_June_Statement.pdf  
07 2017_July_Statement.pdf  
08 2017_August_Statement.pdf  
09 2017_September_Statement.pdf  
10 2017_October_Statement.pdf  
11 2017_November_Statement.pdf  
12 2017_December_Statement.pdf
```

I hope that's clear and will be grateful for any suggestions offered.

[My Previous Research: I'm not able to write the code myself, that's well beyond my competency level, so all I've done so far is try to hunt around (Googling) for snippets of code already written on the net but all the results I'm getting seem to be designed to reorder files based on timestamps rather than month-name strings inside the filenames.]

**Afterthought:**
I would imagine the script would operate something like this:-

```
For n=1 to 12  
Read each filename in turn  
Do  
If filename contains $="jan" then add prefix "01" to filename  
If filename contains $="feb" then add prefix "02" to filename  
               ... and so on, until ...  
If filename contains $="dec" then add prefix "12" to filename  
next n  
End
```

Ideally, the arguments (jan, feb, etc.) would ***not*** be case sensitive.

Many thanks to ***both*** contributors!
I will make a point of learning more about the use of PowerShell scripts (now I've seen how useful they can be and had a look at the ISE that MS have proivided for them and I will also try to figure out how the commands in the very elegant batch script work exactly so I can maybe use the techniques therein myself!
**I've learned a huge amount from this exercise; thanks to all once aagin.**

Many thanks also to the further three contributors who added their solutions to the problem; good of you all to take the time to address the issue.  However, the first (batch) solution offered does exactly what I need so I will be using that from now on.

I suppose this thread could be considered "Closed" now (but I don't know how to do that or even if I CAN do that; perhaps it should be passed to a 'mod' for closure?)

Thanks again to ***all***. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch script will do it too. It's longer than the powershell script.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
    REM Call renameFile on each file in the current folder
    FOR /F "delims=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B') DO (
        CALL :renameFile "%%~F"
    )
(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)



:: ========================================================================
:renameFile
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "FNAME=%~1"
    SET "index=-1"

    REM Check to see if the filename contains this value, done by using logic
    REM that changes the FCOPY variable to replace jan, feb, mar with nothing
    REM and then compare against the original
    FOR %%M IN (jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec) DO (
        CALL :getIndex index "%FNAME%" "%%~M"
        IF !index! NEQ -1    GOTO :renameFile_IndexDone
    )
    :renameFile_IndexDone

    REM index is either -1 (not found) or a value to change, if not found then
    REM don't rename the file
    IF %index% EQU -1    EXIT /B 0

    REM now look to see if the file already has the index - don't want to add it
    REM multiple times
    IF "%FNAME:~0,2%" EQU "%index%"    EXIT /B 0

    REM We have an index and the file hasn't been renamed yet, so rename it
    move /y "%FNAME%" "%index% %FNAME%"
(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)




:: ========================================================================
:getIndex
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET "OUTVAR=%~1"
    SET "FNAME=%~2"
    SET "month=%~3"
    SET "retVal=-1"

    REM Setup replacement variables. Can use full names or just the first three
    REM characters. Currently three characters so it works for full names and
    REM common abbreviation.
    SET "jan=01"
    SET "feb=02"
    SET "mar=03"
    SET "apr=04"
    SET "may=05"
    SET "jun=06"
    SET "jul=07"
    SET "aug=08"
    SET "sep=09"
    SET "oct=10"
    SET "nov=11"
    SET "dec=12"

    SET "FCHECK=!FNAME:%month%=!"

    IF "%FCHECK%" NEQ "%FNAME%" (
        CALL SET "retVal=%%%month%%%"
    )

(ENDLOCAL
    SET "%OUTVAR%=%retVal%"
 EXIT /B 0)
```

Comment: Brilliant!!!  
This works a treat too and I love your extensive "Error Checking"; I noticed that the ps1 script ***does*** add the prefix a second time if you run it on a path it's already been down, lol.  
What's more your script solves my problem of changing the path for each folder (or copying all the files to a specific folder aimed at by the ps1) so I can just run your batch script in any folder I want.  
**Fabulous!**  
Thank you very much!!! :)))

Answer (score 0):

you could create an `*.ps1` file (powershell) and write this code into that file:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Banking\2017\" -Filter '*.pdf' | 

Foreach-Object {
$name = ''
if($_.BaseName -like '*january*') {$name = '01 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*february*') {$name = '02 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*march*') {$name = '03 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*april*') {$name = '04 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*may*') {$name = '05 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*june*') {$name = '06 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*july*') {$name = '07 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*august*') {$name = '08 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*september*') {$name = '09 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*october*') {$name = '10 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*november*') {$name = '11 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}
if($_.BaseName -like '*december*') {$name = '12 ' + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"}

Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $name
}
```

This powershell script will do your job for this example path: `C:\Banking\2017\`, to execute this script just right click and select: `Run with powershell`

enjoy!

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your prompt answer and for taking the trouble to write up code that would do what I need.  Looking at your code I suspect that it would indeed fulfil my requirements.  The only problem is, I have no idea what a Powershell script is or how to create one or, indeed, how to run it either, lol.
Notwithstanding my complete ignorance in that respect (my knowledge extends only to basic writing and execution of batch files) I will certainly have a go at doing what you suggest.  I will have a Google at "Powershell" to see if I can then experiment with your code.  Thanks again. :))

Comment: it's actually very easy, just create an text file with that code and go to File > Save As > in the file type select (All files) and in the name field enter:  myScript.ps1 -> don't forget to mark the question as answered afterward ;)

Comment: Wonderful!  Worked a treat!   All I had to do was flick thru a few pages on how to use ps1's and I was up and running.  I did have to "*Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned*" first I discovered (luckily) then all that was needed was a change to your first line: "Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\wbcam\Desktop\Powershell\2017" -Filter '*.pdf' |" and r/click "Run with PowerShell" worked like a charm! :))  
Thank you very much!

Comment: Silly Question but I''m new here:  How do I mark the question as "Answered"?

Also, is it possible to modify the code so that I can put the ps1 file into a specific folder and it will just work on the files in ***that*** folder alone? ie: automatically set the path to the folder the ps1 is in (I think)

Answer (score 0):

This batch script can did the trick too :

```bat
@echo off
Title Add a numerical prefix to filenames that are based on month strings
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (January February March April May June July August September October November December) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set month[!i!]=%%a
)

@for /L %%j in (1,1,%i%) do (
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ('Dir /B *.pdf ^|find /I "!month[%%j]!"') do (
        Set "FileName=%%~b"
        Call :Trim !FileName! FileName
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [January] Set "Num_Month=01"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [February] Set "Num_Month=02"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [March]    Set "Num_Month=03"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [April]    Set "Num_Month=04"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [May]      Set "Num_Month=05"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [June]     Set "Num_Month=06"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [July]     Set "Num_Month=07"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [August]   Set "Num_Month=08"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [September] Set "Num_Month=09"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [October]   Set "Num_Month=10"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [November] Set "Num_Month=11"
        If /I [!month[%%j]!] EQU [December] Set "Num_Month=12"
        echo renaming file "!FileName!" To "!Num_Month! !FileName!"
        Ren "!FileName!" "!Num_Month! !FileName!"
    )
)
EndLocal
pause & exit
::*************************************************************************
:Trim <String> <Var to Set>
(echo Wscript.echo Trim("%~1"^))>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "%2=%%a"
exit /b
::**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in PowerShell. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
$baseDir = 'C:/src/t/premonth'
$monthHash = @{
    'january' = '01'; 'february' = '02'; 'march' = '03'; 'april' = '04'
    'may' = '05'; 'june' = '06'; 'july' = '07'; 'august' = '08'
    'september' = '09'; 'october' = '10'; 'november' = '11'; 'december' = '12'
}

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $baseDir -Filter '*.pdf' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '^\d{4}_(.*)_Statement.pdf') {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($monthHash[$Matches[1]] + ' ' + $_.Name) -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you asked for a ***simple*** Batch file?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a two-digits NumberOfMonth array
set "i=100"
for %%a in (January February March April May June
            July August September October November December) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "NOM[%%a]=!i:~1!"
)

rem Rename the files
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.pdf') do (
   ren "%%a_%%b_%%c" "!NOM[%%b]! %%a_%%b_%%c"
)
```

This Batch file does what you requested. Of course, it is possible to add more functions. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a two-digits NumberOfMonth array
set "i=100"
for %%a in (January February March April May June
            July August September October November December) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "NOM[%%a]=!i:~1!"
)

rem Rename the files, but only properly formed file names
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_ " %%a in ('dir /B *.pdf') do (
   if defined NOM[%%b] ren "%%a_%%b_%%c" "!NOM[%%b]! %%a_%%b_%%c"
)
```

In this second code an **if** is added to check that the filename has the rigth format, with the month name in the *second* element. A space is also added in the **delims=** FOR clause in order to also detect already renamed files.